# How to animate footer view in all Activity from SD card images (Like footer Adds googleadds,etc)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am new in developing apps for android and I need some help.

I need to animating images in footer from specific path folder in SDCARD for all activity, i use footer layout as common for all layout.

I have writen code for animating images by writing below code:

```
        public void AnimateActionHandler() {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service AnimateActionHandler",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AnimateandSlideShow();
            }
        };
        int delay = 500; // delay for 1 sec.
        int period = 1000; // repeat every 2 sec.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        }, delay, period);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public void AnimateandSlideShow() {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service AnimateandSlideShow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (Config.ImageFilelist.isEmpty()) {
            Config.ImageFilelist = GetFileList(AddsPath);
        }
        if (Config.ImageFilelist.size() <= Config.currentimageindex) {
            Config.currentimageindex = 0;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "ImageFilelist::"+Config.ImageFilelist.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Config.currentimageindex::"+Config.currentimageindex);
        Config.FooterBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Config.ImageFilelist.get(Config.currentimageindex).toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Addbmp"+Config.FooterBitmap.getHeight());
        Config.slidingimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goeasy_footer);
        Config.slidingimage.setImageBitmap(Config.FooterBitmap);
        Log.d(TAG, "JOSEafter");
        Animation rotateimage =     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.splash_anim);
        Config.slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);
        Config.currentimageindex = Config.currentimageindex + 1;
        if (Config.ImageFilelist.size() <= Config.currentimageindex) {
            Config.currentimageindex = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Set image EXC"+e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();

        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError oe) {
        try{

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Now i would like to play this animation in footer for all screens by service, How can i fix this one, Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why you animate with code though you have facility of Animation Classes in android.

Try following example.

[Animation Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) ,[Frame Animation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/frame-by-frame-animation/) and [Other animation exmples](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html#animations)

Comment: Animating images not think for me, i need to randomized the images in footer for all screens in common background services, i kept images in SD card, i dont want call in each activity, would like to set in background service for specific imageview